# MagicalRecords importFromArray return empty array

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1, magicalrecord-2.2

I am using the code below for create my Team `NSManagedObjects`. But when I print my array object the Xcode console says me the array is empty.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
{
    NSArray *array = [Team MR_importFromArray:objects inContext:localContext];   
}
completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
{

}];
```

The completion block invokes but I don't understand why? The objects were not created. Any suggestions or workarounds?

The Magical records seems create the records, but with some delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MagicalRecord 2.2 has a bug that isn't saving imports. Use version [2.0.8](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/2.0.8). It has `saveWithBlock`

Comment: Hello thank you for answer but are you sure that I need to use version 2.1, because I have switched to 2.1 and the array still empty when I print it.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander try 2.0 I know it is one of those as I had this issue last week. I am using a custom version of MagicalRecord so cannot check the correct version.

Comment: bad news, in version 2.0 we are not able to using block (

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander i'm not understanding what you are trying to say by not able using block.

Comment: sorry I meant version 2.0 has not got save with block feature

Comment: very strange issue that the MR_importFromArray does not return array of imported object, but the objects were saved as I can check in few moments if i going through the few view controllers. it means import objects works but does not return array

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander view my updated answer. 2.0.8 is the version you want with `saveWithBlock`

Comment: also I would submit a bug so they go and look at it.

Comment: ok thanks seems everything is goes fine, i think there is no additional issues ) I use saveInBackgroundWithBlock now

Answer (score 0):

Add logging of the error in your completion handler to get more information about the issue:

```
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Also, have a look into this thread on GitHub:

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/656

Comment: I have print error Error: (null) and then print NSArray *arr = [Team MR_findAll]; but the arr is empty

Comment: What about the `success` flag? Is it `true` or `false`?

Comment: it is false, but honestly it false every time even when I got object